# Simple get initials from string - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Simple beginner exercise:

There's an input box where you put in your name seperated by spaces, then get the first letter from the first and last name and out put it to a label

I.e (Joe Bob) = JB

---

I know this could be done with an array, but the exercise is more to using string functions like substring, IndexOf, Remove, Replace etc...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using the [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) Methods.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myInitials As String
    Dim myName As String = "Joe Bob"
    myInitials = myName.Substring(0, 1) & myName.Split(" ")(1).Substring(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. Just a question so I may better understand: Could you explain what substring(0,1) and then ...(1).Substring(0,1) are doing exactly?

Comment: @DavidSalib As some of the answers have pointed out, strings are arrays of chars, what `substring(0,1)` does is get the first character from position 0 of the first string. `Split(" ")(1)` then splits the string into 2 strings and `Substring(0,1)` gets the first character from position zero of the second string. Be aware that there is no checking in my example to make sure that the input is in the proper format.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! Yes I added stuff like Trim() and replacing periods, and limiting it to only one space.

Answer (score 1):

There is the handy string method `Split` which splits a string at whitespaces by default, if you don't specify another delimiter.

```
Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split()
Dim initials As String = ""
For Each word As String In words
    initials &= word(0)
Next
```

Note: Strings can be indexed as if they were `Char` arrays. `word(0)` is the first character of `word`.

```
initials &= word(0)
```

is shorthand for

```
initials = initials & word(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 dim str as String=TextBox1.Text
 Label1.Text=str.Remove(1, str.LastIndexOf(" ")).Remove(2)
```

If you want, you can do it in one line:

```
 Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(1, TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ")).Remove(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this too!

```
Dim str As String = textBox1.Text
Dim initials As String = New String(str.Split(" "c).Select(Function(f) f(0)).ToArray)
```

Comment: I like your idea, because of LINQ , but at the end you use ToArray , something that DavidSalib tries to avoid.

Comment: it's just due to the string constructor requiring a char array

Comment: Yes I know. I am not trying to accuse you, and I really like your answer.

Comment: That's ok, people had provided good answers before me, so I thought I'd post this, even though as you rightly mentioned the OP wanted to avoid using certain features :)